# Rebind an owned variable inside a FnMut closure

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

I am unable to rebind an owned variable that I have moved into a `FnMut()` closure. I think the following MRE summarises the problem.

```rust
fn takes_closure(mut do_something: impl FnMut()) {
    do_something()
}

fn main() {
    let test_string = String::from("hello");

    takes_closure(move || {
        //let mut test_string = test_string; // 1
        let mut test_string = test_string.clone(); // 2
        test_string.push_str("!"); // 3
    });
}
```

The target behaviour would be that `test_string` has a `!` appended to it each time the closure is called. Please note that it is not possible to rebind `test_string` in `main` as mutable due to the context of the original problem. These are the following issues that I have found:

1. Is not possible because this is "moving" out of the closure
2. Is incorrect since now I am modifying a copy of the string and not the original
3. Only works with #2 since it requires `test_string` to be bound mutably.

Comment: I've very hard time imagining a way you cannot mark the variable as mutable in main. Maybe it is a shared reference and you cannot change it? In that case, better change the example code to use a shared reference too.

Comment: I think we need more context on the original problem. A solution here may be invalid there.

Comment: In the original problem, the variable that is moved into the closure is bound immutably by a [macro](https://docs.rs/dominator/latest/src/dominator/macros.rs.html#137-154) which I do not have control over:

Comment: Can you show us the original code?

Comment: So rebind it‽ If you can move it, you can also rebind it.

Comment: @cafce25 this is what I thought I should be able to do. But it is not possible. You get an error about moving out of the closure.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman if you are asking how that macro is invocated, it would be like this: `let closure_with_clone = clone!(test_string => move || { test_string.push_str("!")})`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this is the second option in cafce25's answer and does indeed work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare `test_string` as mutable before the closure, either by directly making the original mutable:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut test_string = String::from("hello");

    takes_closure(move || {
        test_string.push_str("!"); // 3
    });
}
```

or if you want to retain immutability until just before the closure, rebinding the variable just outside of the closure

```rust
fn main() {
    let test_string = String::from("hello");

    takes_closure({
        let mut test_string = test_string;
        move || {
            test_string.push_str("!"); // 3
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to modify the original `test_string` and observe the change after the closure ran you have to move just a mutable reference in:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut test_string = String::from("hello");

    takes_closure({
        let test_string = &mut test_string;
        move || {
            test_string.push_str("!"); // 3
        }
    });

    dbg!(test_string); // outputs 'test_string = "hello!"'
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet is not an option. The second option is a viable workaround and is probably as close as I am going to get to a solution. The third option doesn't work in the context of the original problem since the closure has to have a static lifetime.

Comment: @mallwright The second option is also used in more common scenarios, such as when you need to clone or reference a variable before capturing it in a `move` closure (which has to be `move` for the sake of _other_ captured variables, which you do want to move). Maybe calling it "idiomatic" would be a bit too much, but I've definitely seen it before.